# Why are my box plots narrow when I colour them with plotly?

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to plot the data I have stored in a pandas DataFrame using plotly.express as a box plot. The df looks like the following:

[image]

---

This is my code for making the basic boxplot graph in plotly:

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.box(df1, x="Condition",
             y="Number of Groups")
fig.show()
```

Giving as a result the kind of graph I was looking for:
[image]

Now, I wanna color each condition in a different color for what I use:

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.box(df1, x="Condition",
             y="Number of Groups",
             color="Condition")
fig.show()
```

Giving me this graph in which now the box plots are much narrower than normal. Does anybody knows how to avoid this? Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a bug which has been fixed in version 4.8 of `plotly` and a workaround for versions below that is to add `boxmode="overlay"` inside the `px.box()` call when `color` is set to the same value as `x`. And I should add that the same applies to `px.violin` and `px.strip` plots with `violinmode` and `stripmode`, respectively :)

Comment: Possible regression problem, the bug occurs in version 5.13.0. The proposed fix still works.

Comment: Strange! if you're seeing a regression, could you please open a Github issue with a reproducible test case? thanks!

Comment: Actually, I see that the same behavior occurs in Seaborn (using hue="..."). There, dodge=False, solves the issue. I may have just missed a feature. I'll investigate a little more when I find the time.